# Problem after update

Tags: updates, system

I recently updated Ubuntu MATE and installed Ubuntu 22.04. After I installed the latest version, sometimes when I open a particular software or file (for example when I open a new tab in browser or open a pdf file with my pdf reader) I suddenly get logged out of my account.